# How to use the advanced partitioning menu?

Tags: partitioning

I would like to install ubuntu making my own partitions... How do I do that? (please note I am not an advanced computer user)

Comment: do you have any other OS on that system? if so... can it be deleted or does it have to be side by side with the other OS? Please edit your question with the answers :)

Comment: This person has a video showing the process. [link](http://thelinuxvideo.com/?p=139).

Answer (score 0):

if you are running windows now... http://opensource-sidh.blogspot.com/2011/10/install-ubuntu-1110-and-windows-dual.html

Think this will be helpful

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The blog post http://linuxnorth.wordpress.com/manual-partitioning/ provides basic information on setting up root and swap areas using the manual partitioner, and has a number of references to useful web sites, including video tutorials.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.